# Insert line in to pattern on text file python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, io

I have a text file that takes the form of:

```
first thing:    content 1
second thing:   content 2
third thing:    content 3
fourth thing:   content 4
```

This pattern repeats throughout the entire text file.  However, sometimes one of the rows is completely gone like so:

```
first thing:    content 1
second thing:   content 2
fourth thing:   content 4
```

How could I search the document for these missing rows and just add it back with a value of "NA" or some filler to produce a new text file like this:

```
# 'third thing' was not there, so re-adding it with NA as content
first thing:    content 1
second thing:   content 2
third thing:    NA 
fourth thing:   content 4
```

Current code boilerplate:

```
with open('original.txt, 'r') as in:
    with open('output.txt', 'wb') as out:
        #Search file for pattern (Maybe regex?)
        #If pattern does not exist, add the line
```

Thanks for any help you all can offer!

Comment: is there an identifier for the lines that we can detect the missing lines?

Comment: Unfortunately no, in this file any row could be missing so I will have to account for that, but what I can tell you that the format of the text files the same, in that there are a block of 4, or less, rows, and then a blank line in between them.  This pattern lasts anywhere from 5-50 times.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a delimiter between the *blocks*? If not, line `1, 2, 3, 4` could really be two blocks: `line 1 & 2 with missing 3 & 4` **plus** `missing 1 & 2 followed by line 3 & 4`...

Comment: In raw text it would look like line1\n line2\n line3\n line4\n \n line 1 \n line 2 \n line 4 \n, etc.

Comment: I don't know if that's an answer to my question (include @Username in answers ;), but does that mean that there's a blank line between the blocks? (the extra `\n` between the *blocks*)

Comment: @ClasG That is correct.  There is a blank line in between blocks. That's the delimeter between blocks of content.  Each row in a block is on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You must look for 1-3 lines (less than 4) followed by newline:

```
^\n([^\n]*\n){1,3}\n
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rL3eA5/2

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty, but it works. Here's a regex to detect where lines are missing:

```
(?:^|\n)(second thing:\s*[^\n]+\n)|(first thing:\s*[^\n]+\n(?!second thing:))|(second thing:\s*[^\n]+\n(?!third thing:))|(third thing:\s*[^\n]+\n(?!fourth thing:))|(third thing:\s*[^\n]+\n\n)
```

[regex101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rI8dB1/3)

Notice the `Single Line` flag.

When you've got a match, check which match group that matches. If it's the first one, the first line is missing. If it's the second one, the second line is missing and so on for third and fourth.

[Here's an example how to replace if the 1'st group got a match](https://regex101.com/r/rI8dB1/7).

[Here's an example how to replace if the 3'rd group got a match](https://regex101.com/r/rI8dB1/5).

[Here's an example how to replace if the 4'rd group got a match](https://regex101.com/r/rI8dB1/6).

You'll probably have to do some tweaking, but it should get you on your way ;)

Regards.